# Java: to pick out random phrase out of a string array

Tags: java

I declared a string array of 5 phrases. Im having trouble with printing out only one phrase randomly out of the array. My code below generates several phrases. How do I only print out one?

```
    int length = arr.length;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * length);
        
        System.out.println(arr[rand]);
    }
```

Comment: Why the `for` loop? Is `arr` the array of phrases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just generate one number and call it to the array index. You dont need `for loop` because you are not generating multiple numbers.
Simple with `random.nextInt(arrayWord.length);` you generate numbers **0 - array Length**

```
public class RandomNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] arrayWord = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Tes5"};

        Random random = new Random();

        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(arrayWord.length);


        System.out.println(arrayWord[randomNumber]);
    }
}
```